Measure Botpress message response time using Locust.io and Python
We integrate Botpress into our website and want to use Locust.io to perform performance test. But I see that the response time of Create Message API is not enough. I want to measure the time: from Create Message API is sent, to the Bot Message is shown on message list. How can I do that without calling List Message API again and again (which can put more load on the bot)?
I see this code to real time listen the botResponse in Botpress documents (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botpress/chat):
const listener = await client.listenConversation({
  id: conversationId,
})

const botResponse = await new Promise<chat.Message>((resolve) => {
  const onMessage = (ev: chat.Events['message_created']) => {
    if (ev.userId === client.user.id) {
      // message created by my current user, ignoring...
      return
    }
    listener.off('message_created', onMessage)
    resolve(ev)
  }
  listener.on('message_created', onMessage)
})

console.log("Bot's response:", botResponse.payload)

But I don't know how to do the same in Python?

Translating code isn't exactly what this site is for.

I have no idea what botpress is or if there is a python lib for it. If it communicates over websockets then maybe you can find inspiration here https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/users/socketio.py

@LukeL I didn't mean translating code, just wanted to apply the same solution to my Locust script.

@Cyberwiz Thank you! The link is very useful. I'm trying to apply.
